# How to manage (check if installed, stop, start, restart) services/software on Linux with PHP?

Tags: php, linux

What I want to do with PHP on a Linux system:

- Check if software is installed (e.g. Redis)
- Start/Stop/Restart the service/software (like systemctl start|stop|restart redis.service)

This should be done by means of a graphical GUI with PHP backend.

Is there any convenient PHP-library suited for managing software on Linux, which also checks which distribution you use and adapts to the specifics of the used distribution, or do I have to use shell_exec() function in conjunction with shell commands to manage installed services?

What is the best way to achieve this with PHP?

Comment: why not just read the .ini file for modules loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could be a bit more specific, please?

Comment: Not quite what your after - but IMHO a good solution is Docker-PHP (https://github.com/docker-php/docker-php) which allows you to manage Docker containers.  This isn't about loading modules though, more about microservice management.

Comment: you could use `fopen` to read your server ini file and search the string for the loaded modules

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in your question, I use shell_exec for this :

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('service apache2 status');
var_dump($output);
?>

// Output : ... Active: active (running) ...
```